# Swift & Parse Server Config: How to add a "Message of the Day" cell at the top of a tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform, parse-server

**Goal:**
I'm trying to add a dynamic "Message of the Day" kind of cell to the top of a `UITableView` in Swift using Parse Server Config. Similar to how you see a new cell at the top of your Facebook iOS app feed that's related to the current time/day (i.e.: "Good morning, SomeName" or "It's Election Day! Go Vote!"). See screenshot below for an example (the cell inside the red lines).

**What I've done:** I've read the [Parse Config iOS docs](http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/ios/guide/#config) and have added a key/value pair (parameter) to the app on the Parse Config Dashboard.

**My code for retrieving the Parse Config:**

```
// Retrieving my Parse Config:
PFConfig.getConfigInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (var config: PFConfig?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if error == nil {
    var message = config?["MessageOfTheDay"] as? NSString
    print("Today's message of the day: \(message)")
  } else {
    print("Failed to fetch. Using Cached Config.")
    config = PFConfig.currentConfig()
  }
```

*Now that I have the "Message of the Day", I need help please with adding a table view cell showing this message of the day.*

**What I need help with:**
How to dynamically add a cell (with the text and/or image returned from the Parse Config to the top of the `UITableView` (at `indexPath.row == 1`) when I add a new "Message of the Day!" parameter in Parse Config Dashboard.

**Example scenario:**
Today is Election Day. If I go into my Parse Config Dashboard and add the following parameter - **key: "Message", value: "Today is Election Day!"**, then open the client iOS app, I expect to see inside the `UITableView` feed a new cell at `indexPath.row == 1` with the text, "Today is Election Day!" Tomorrow, when I open the app again, I should not see this cell anymore.

Appreciate any help. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: You seem to have two completely separate and overly broad questions here. Please focus the question to one task. Do you need help accessing the data from your Parse server or do you need help adding a row to a table view based on some data (regardless of where it came from)? Pick one and update your question to be specific to that one issue. Then update your question with details about what you have done so far and what issues you are having.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks. I updated my question based on your feedback.

Comment: Since it seems you wish to focus on the part for adding the table cell, you need to update your question with relevant code showing what you have done to add the table cell. Show what part you need help with. Your question is still far too vague and broad.

Comment: @rmaddy I updated my question again with code I'm using to retrieve the Parse config and what I now need help with: adding a new table view cell to the top of the tableview, if there is a message of the day.

Comment: @rmaddy I've updated my question - hopefully it's clearer. Are you able to help me now? I've If my question is still not clear, please let me know.